# How to return from two for-loops in php

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to return col1_2,col2_2,col3_2,col4_2,col1_3,col2_3,col3_3,col4_3,col1_4 ...etc so that I can use it in other function.

So I made like this.

```
function _fields($keynum){
    for ($r=2; $r<$keynum; $r++){
        for($c=1; $c<5; $c++){
            $colname="col".$c."_".$r;
            return $colname.",";
        }
    }
}

function create(){
    if ($this->input->post('keynum')){
        $keynum=$this->input->post('keynum');
        $output = $this->_fields($keynum);
        $output=explode(",", $output);
        $data['output']=$output;
       ...
       ...
```

However function _fields() returns only col1_2.
If I echo out instead of return $colname.","; It echo outs col1_2,col2_2,col3_2,col4_2. But this can't be used in function create().

I will be appreciate your input.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like

```
function _fields($keynum){
     $colname = '';
    for ($r=2; $r<$keynum; $r++){
        for($c=1; $c<5; $c++){
            $colname .= "col".$c."_".$r;
        }
    }
    return  $colname;
}
```

[Here's a live demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PJnEKu)

Comment: but how can he explode all the columns no , is added after column name

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the individual column names as generated in the `_fields` function, you can use an array instead of a string:

```
function _fields($keynum){
    $colname = array();
    for ($r=2; $r<$keynum; $r++){
        for($c=1; $c<5; $c++){
            $colname[] = "col".$c."_".$r;
        }
    }
    return  $colname;
}
```

Now you don't have to `explode` anything in your `create` function:

```
function create(){
    if ($this->input->post('keynum')){
        $keynum=$this->input->post('keynum');
        $output = $this->_fields($keynum);
        foreach ($output as $col){
          echo $col;
        }
       ...
       ...
```

Comment: exactly my answer, but you typed faster